# Making a sudoku solver

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to make a sudoku solver program which gets a vector of vectors as an input where each vector inside the vector is a row of the sudoku, where each '0' is an empty cell in the sudoku.

Until now, I've found every possible number a cell with '0' can get.

So the problem is this, after finding which cell has only one possible solution, how will i put that unique solution onto its position despite the immutability of Clojure?

The program needs to return that same vector of vectors where each '0' is replaced by a number which meets the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a vector of vectors, you can set a cell value using `assoc-in` e.g.

```
(def cells [[1 3 0]
            [4 2 1]
            [6 3 0]])

(defn set-cell-value [board row col value]
    (assoc-in board [row col] value))

(set-cell-value cells 0 2 2)
```

Comment: I will definitelly try this

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have state, put it into `atom` https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom It is a mutable reference type which holds immutable values.

Comment: I basically need to put that unique value onto its position in the original matrix, one thinf ive been thinking about is making an acumulator matrix and put the elements there but if its empty u cant put them at the corrent index